# Double pointers

Tags: c++, linked-list

I'm struggling with the following code. I want to create a linked list and keep track of its head. However, when I assign a pointer to the first node created, I am able to access only the first node's data value, and not its next nodes.
ie) the code below produces 
0
Why won't it print out all values in the linked list ( 0 - 4 ) ?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct node
{
    int val;
    node * next = nullptr;
    node(int a)
    {
        val = a;
    }
};
node * t = nullptr;
node * temp;

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        t = new node (i);
        if (i ==0)
        {
            temp = t;
        }
        t = t->next;
    }
    while (temp!=nullptr)
    {
        cout << (temp)->val;
        temp = (temp)->next;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: because you do not assign next field in your code

Comment: `t = t->next;` t->next is a nullptryou use it like that!? think about it. :)

Comment: Read https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Answer (score 0):

During the creation of the list you need to keep track of the node created previously and set the next pointer of that node to the node you just created.

You probably want this:

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
  node *head;
  node *previous = NULL;

  for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
  {
    node *t = new node(i);

    if (i == 0)
    {
      head = t;
    }

    if (previous != nullptr)  // if not first node
    {
      previous->next = t;     //    set next of previous node to current node
    }

    previous = t;
  }

  node *temp = head;
  while (temp != nullptr)
  {
    cout << temp->val << endl;
    temp = temp->next;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

The overall design of this code is still poor but it sticks as closely as possible to the original code.

Output:

```
0
1
2
3
4
```